# Wacom Cintiq Pro 13 or 24?

Tags: illustration, drawing-tablet, wacom, hardware-recommendation, hardware

Good evening.

So my Companion 2 just died and I'm looking to upgrade. Wacom tech support quoted a repair at $1,113 which I consider too high, but they also offered me 10% off of the Wacom eStore. Refurbished items sold on eBay by Wacom also come with a 1 year warranty so that's an option as well.

Now my dilemma: I'm stuck between getting the Cintiq Pro 13 - which is the same size as what I'm used to with the Companion 2 - or the Cintiq Pro 24. From what I gather, the 24 is the professional-preferred model, and I am very interested in being able to use my whole arm to draw rather than just my wrist (I've never had that much real estate before). However, the 24 is 2.5 times more expensive than the 13.

At the time I type this, the Pro 13 would be $763.15 with the 10% off, including my state's 6% sales tax. The Pro 24 would be $1907.95 after the discount and tax. So for about double the screen size, the Pro 24 is about 2.5 times more expensive. I am also aware of the Pro 16, which is 3 inches bigger than the Pro 13, but it costs $1430.95 after sales tax and discount, which is 1.9 times the price of the Pro 13 for only 3" more for $477 less than the Pro 24...

I am not currently a professional, but I used my Cintiq more-or-less daily. I am planning to go back and get another degree in the multimedia field and become a full-time multimedia professional, so I suppose I would be considered a prosumer. So is the 24 really that much better for someone like me to be worth the price, or would I be better off with the very slight upgrade to the Cintiq Pro 13?

Comment: Should I have chicken or fish for dinner???  I understand the desire for input but I don't think anyone here can determine what's best *for you* and *your use*. Is the 24" better.. well it's more than 10" larger.. so yes... Would you prefer an 24" laptop or a 13" laptop? Beyond that.. it's a matter of budget.

Comment: C13 Pro has a 1080p screen while 24Pro has a 4k. For 1080p I’d go with Cintiq 16 (non-pro): it’s great and doesn’t have fans. Or new 22 HD. But I agree with Scott, it’s an opinion based question that’s impossible to answer

Comment: Product reviews on hardware are really off-topic here. There are review sites for that kind of thing. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hmm... alright, sorry if it's off-topic, I saw similar posts here asking for advice and opinions here and this was more specific than those so I thought it was within the guidelines. I'm not seeking black-and-white facts, just unbiased advice and opinions from real people in the field who weren't given a product to review. I even called Best Buy to try them out in person but they're closed due to a global pandemic. Also I think a multi-hundred dollar purchase is a bit more significant than chicken or fish, I feel that was a little harsh my guy. Your opinions are all I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't meaning to be insulting. It's just kind of along the same lines... You can't possibly know what I would prefer... that's all. In the end it's Wacom vs Wacom.. so it's really more a matter of preference than anything else.

Comment: No worries. It just sucks I can't try them both out in person, but it is what it is. I'll continue doing research and looking at videos and whatnot, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one big sheet of paper, of the size of each model of monitor you want to try, put some marks on the active area... And imagine they are the actual monitor. Make the kind of drawings you are used to do and define if YOU need it. ;o)

The only one that can answer if you need it is you.

Comment: It's funny you say that, I actually did exactly that! I clipped a roughly 13" and 24" piece of paper to a thin wood board then put it on an easel and drew the same thing on both, and it did help. I have decided that I do want a larger screen as it would offer more flexibility in art style (whole arm vs just the wrist), so this is the advice I would give to other people to try as well. Now it's down to the Cintiq 22 and 24 for me, and I have to think whether the 4k is worth the extra $600-700, but at least I've narrowed down the general size I want. Thank you to everybody who posted :)